# How to find x intercept of $y=x-\arctan 2x$

Tags: functions

I can express the function as:

$$x = \arctan 2x$$

Or:

$$\tan x = 2x$$

I can deduct that one root is $x = 0$. But do I find the other two roots?

Comment: You'll have to use a numerical method unfortunately (Newton's method, e.g.).

Comment: You might be able to use the asymptotic series and try a series reversion.

Comment: Using the first 3 terms in the asymptotic expansion,
$$\displaystyle{y\sim x-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{2x}=0\rightarrow x=\frac{\pi+\sqrt{\pi^2-8}}{4}\approx1.12723\dots}$$
A relative error of about $3\%$. Taking more terms will yield better results, but becomes it becomes very impractical by hand.

Comment: As a side comment, note that $\tan(x)=2x$ has more solutions that $x=\arctan(2x)$.  The latter has an interval as image, and when you apply $\tan$ (which is periodic in its common form) it extends the image to the reals (beside discontinuities at $\pm n\pi/2,\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$). If you prefer to numerically solve $\tan(x)=2x$, you will then need to eliminate the solutions outside of the image of the first equation.

Comment: Would you like an explicit solution?

Comment: If you look at my edit, we have the funny (unknown) approximation  $$\frac \pi 2 \sim \sqrt{14-\sqrt{133}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cjferes commented, the simplest is to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\tan(x)-2x \qquad \text{with} \qquad -\frac \pi 2 <x<\frac \pi 2$$ For a first approximation, using one of the simplest Padé approximants
$$\tan(x)\sim \frac{x \left(15-x^2\right)}{15-6 x^2}$$ reduces the problem to
$$x \left(11 x^2-15\right)=0$$ and $$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{15}{11}}=\pm 1.16775$$ is not bad at all (the "exact" solution being $1.16556$.

The next  Padé approximant
$$\tan(x) \sim \frac{x \left(x^4-105 x^2+945\right)}{15 \left(x^4-28
   x^2+63\right)}$$  reduces the problem to
$$x \left(29 x^4-735 x^2+945\right)=0$$ and
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{58} \left(245-\sqrt{47845}\right)}=\pm 1.16556$$ is almost exact (absolute error equal to $7.0 \times 10^{-7}$)

The next  Padé approximant
$$\tan(x)\sim \frac{x \left(x^6-378 x^4+17325 x^2-135135\right)}{7 \left(4   x^6-450 x^4+8910 x^2-19305\right)}$$  reduces the problem to
$$x \left(55 x^6-5922 x^4+107415 x^2-135135\right)=0$$ and solving the cubic in $y^2$ using the trigonometric solution leads to

$$x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1974}{55}-\frac{2}{55} \sqrt{1927401} \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi }{6}+\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{65568471 \sqrt 3}{183562
   \sqrt{642467}}\right)\right)}$$

(absolute error equal to $4.8 \times 10^{-11}$)

**Edit**

If we use the second given Padé approximant, the non trivial solution of
$$\tan(x)= k x$$ is given by
$$(15 k-1) x^4-105 (4 k-1) x^2+945 (k-1)=0$$ that is to say
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{140 k-35-\sqrt{35} \sqrt{380 k^2-88 k+23}}{15 k-1}}$$ which seems to be quite decent

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 1.165561886 &  1.165561185 \\
 3 & 1.324196753 &  1.324194450 \\
 4 & 1.393252789 &  1.393249075 \\
 5 & 1.432037046 &  1.432032236 \\
 6 & 1.456898432 &  1.456892774 \\
 7 & 1.474198947 &  1.474192620 \\
 8 & 1.486934424 &  1.486927561 \\
 9 & 1.496701896 &  1.496694594 \\
 10 & 1.504430980 &  1.504423313 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The asymtotics of the estimate is
$$x=\sqrt{14-\sqrt{133}}-\frac{\sqrt{7 \left(2450+131 \sqrt{133}\right)}}{60\sqrt{19}\, k}$$

In other words,
$$\frac \pi 2 \sim \sqrt{14-\sqrt{133}} $$ for an aboslute error of $1.16\times 10^{-5}$

Using the last given Padé approximant
$$\frac \pi 2 \sim$$ $$ \sqrt{\frac{75}{2}-\frac{3}{2} \sqrt{295} \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{793}{59 \sqrt{295}}\right)\right)+\sqrt{3} \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{793}{59
   \sqrt{295}}\right)\right)\right) }$$
for an aboslute error of $2.70\times 10^{-9}$

Answer (score 0):

You can graph it to get a sense for where to search for the solution, but after that you have to use a numerical technique. Also, by symmetry, you can look for the root $\alpha$ and the other root is $-\alpha$.[image]

$\tan(x)-2x$ is monotonic in a range around where the root exists (e.g. from 1 to 1.2, so you can simply refine the solution using binary search.